# modern events calendar excerpt

Tags: wordpress, events, calendar

is there any way to add characters/words for this wordpress plug-in? 
http://webnus.co/plugins/modern-events-calendar/list-view-standard-style/

I would like it to have 3 sentences as the summary.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the wordpress default excerpt